# Is this description of lift and drag coefficients correct?

Tags: aerodynamics, principles-of-flight

In my course (Principles of Flight) written:

> The effect of CLift is not linear. This means that Lift doubles for
> double the lift coefficient.

And

> The effect of CDrag is linear. This means that for double the drag
> coefficient the drag force doubles.

If it's correct? And if yes, why effect of CL is not linear? Seems the same for me: coefficient doubles - force doubles.

Answer (score 3):

The quoted text is in error. Lift (for a given airspeed) is directly (linearly) proportional to the lift coefficient.  Lift (for a given lift coefficient) is proportional to airspeed squared.  Likewise, Drag (for a given airspeed) is directly (linearly) proportional to the drag coefficient.  Drag (for a given drag coefficient) is proportional to airspeed squared.

Comment: Thank you for explaining